# How to query multiple models in Django using a variable as the models name

Tags: django, django-models

I have multiple models such as

```
class PendingResults(models.Model):
nct_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
event = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
event_date_description = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
event_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
...
```

or

```
class ParticipantFlows(models.Model):
nct_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
recruitment_details = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
pre_assignment_details = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
...
```

I would like to query the models using a variable as the model's name such as:

```
model_name='mymodel'
content = *modle_name*.objects.all()
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the `getattr()` function:

```py
from myapp import models

model_name = 'mymodel'
klass = getattr(models, model_name)
content = klass.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
from django.apps import apps


DynamicModel = apps.get_model("app_label", "model_name")

print(DynamicModel.objects.all())
```

And there is another way if you don't know the `app_label`, but take care if you want to use this way you shouldn't define two **models** with the same name in your apps.

```
from django.apps import apps
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType


content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model="model_name")
DynamicModel = apps.get_model(content_type.app_label, "model_name")

print(DynamicModel.objects.all())
```

you can use `DynamicModel` to query.